# How do you do negative Lookahead/Lookbehind in the gitignore files?

Tags: git, gitignore

I am using git for a project and want to exclude a specific subfolder from a path but not the siblings of that folder For example:

```
/Testpath/TestpathA
/Testpath/TestpathB
/Testpath/TestpathC
```

I want to ignore TestpathA and C (and any other paths that may be siblings of those folders, but not TestpathB

I tried

```
/Testpath/*
!/Testpath/TestpathB
```

but that didn't work.

I also tried
    /Testpath/(?!TestpathB)/*

but that didn't work either.

Comment: I changed your tags - gitignores don't use regex; they use a particular flavor of globbing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about;

```
Testpath/*
!Testpath/TestpathB
```

Edit: Actually, strike that, your example works just fine for me as well. What exactly is it you are doing that isn't working? Besides creating the `.gitignore`, what commands are you running?

Comment: @Nemo157
That seemed to work, the problem was I had 
    !TestPath/TestpathB/*
Which didn't work and still allowed the whole folder to be negated

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
/Testpath/*
!/Testpath/TestpathB
```

worked for me:

```
→ cat .gitignore
/Testpath/*
!/Testpath/TestpathB

→ tree
.
└── Testpath
    ├── TestpathA
    │   └── testfile
    ├── TestpathB
    │   └── testfile
    └── TestpathC
        └── testfile

4 directories, 3 files

→ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .gitignore
#       Testpath/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

→ git add .

→ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   .gitignore
#       new file:   Testpath/TestpathB/testfile
#
```

Comment: well I think the leading path is there to ignore the folders off the root and not recursively down the directory tree

Comment: @indigo0086: I think you're right, I added it back in and it still worked.  Posted the output from my tests.

Comment: Thanks for testing, it worked for me just had written it write in the post but not in what I was actually doing.