# Git - Ignore directories based on their contents

Tags: regex, git, gitignore, regex-lookarounds

Using `.gitignore`, is there a way to ignore a directory if it contains a certain file (or directory)?

This would be something like look-ahead assertions, though my use case is a little different:  I want to ignore Mercurial repos in my project, to keep from accidentally committing them as part of the project.  That is, I want to ignore all directories containing `.hg`, not just `.hg` itself.

I can work around this using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809370/how-do-you-do-negative-lookahead-lookbehind-in-the-gitignore-files), adding each directory name to `.gitignore`, but I'd like to make it more general if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it beside adding all of them to your `.gitignore` file.

What you can do it to write a scipt which append all the desired paths to your `.gitignore`.

The content of `.gitignore` is alist of paths so git can be configured based upon content.

> Each line in a gitignore file specifies a pattern